# How can I put a \caption to an image when I'm using overpic?

Tags: captions, overpic

I am trying to do something like this:

```
\begin{overpic}[scale=0.3]{Sistema}\label{fig1}

\caption[Fig1]{Sistema de flujo (abierto) definido por la línea interrumpida.}

\end{overpic}
```

I want to put the description, like when I use `\includegraphics` , but there seems to be something that it's not good, and I can't see it. 
Oh, and, how can I put this image in the List of Figures?

Can anyone help me? Please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `overpic` environment inside the `figure` float environment, and place the caption outside of the `overpic` environment but in the `figure` environment, if you want to be able to use `\caption`. Like you would do with `\includegraphics`.

As a result, this will be added to the list of figures.

Example here:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{overpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{overpic}[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}

\end{overpic}

\caption[Fig1]{Sistema de flujo (abierto) definido por la línea interrumpida.}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Allison: The proper way to thank a user providing a solution is to upvote and accept the answer ;-)